# 500 error for HTTP server request timeout?

Tags: tomcat, server, timeout, http-error

Normally when a HTTP request to the server gets timed out, server will return "408 Request Timeout" error. Is it possible for server to return the "500 Internal Server" error instead?

I am asking this because I am working on a web application. I know the task for the server takes a very long time to complete, so I am expecting a timeout anyway. When I monitor the AJAX request to the server, the request gets terminated almost exactly after 60 seconds +/- 0.5. This seems very likely to be server timeout. However, I am getting "500 Internal Server" error instead of 408.

It is a Spring application running on Tomcat. I have limited access to the server so I can't see the server log to see what exactly was going on.

P.S. I know this kind of behaviour sometimes happens on Apache HTTP Web server, but would that happen on Tomcat too?

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
```

You can insert this line to your applications.properties file and this means,

- `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/` This one uses mysql as the database service. I think this can changed by using relavent name and the port of your database name.
- `database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` = use the database named database if you haven't already make a database like that, make a new one.
- `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` = to allow the client to automatically request the public key from the server. (This part might be additional).
- `useSSL=false` = This will disable SSL and also suppress the SSL errors.

Furthermore, be alert about the `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` property in the same file.

Finally check whether you've added following dependency in dependencies in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are few steps you can try to troubleshoot and resolve the "500 Internal Server Error" response that you are seeing in your Spring application running on Tomcat:

- Check the server logs for messages that might provide more information about the error. The logs might contain stack traces or other details that can help you understand what went wrong.
- Enable debugging in your server-side code. You can do this by adding log statements or by using a debugger to step through the code and see what is happening at each stage. This can help you identify the specific line of code or operation that is causing the error.
- Verify that the server has sufficient resources to handle the request. If the server is running out of memory or CPU while trying to process the request, this can cause it to become unresponsive or to crash, resulting in a "500" response.
- Check the server's error handling configuration. Make sure that the server is configured to return a "408 Request Timeout" response in the event of a timeout, rather than a "500 Internal Server Error" response.
- Test the server's handling of different types of requests. Try making a variety of requests to the server, including both valid and invalid requests, and see how it responds. This can help you identify any patterns or issues with the server's handling of requests.

By following these steps, you should be able to identify the cause of the "500 Internal Server Error" response and take appropriate action to resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).